# CSS Cover image with no re-adjustments

Tags: html, css

I want to have something like facebook cover, I came across [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w2fLqzc/) in this community.

```
.cover { width: 100%; height: 180px; overflow: hidden; background-color: black; }
.cover > img { position: relative; width: 100%; top: 50%; margin-top: -50%; }
```

But there is a problem when I see the cover image in the responsive mode the image re-adjusts itself! i.e in desktop mode in the bycycle driver's head does not show, but in other small device modes the driver's head is visible.

#### Question:

How can I make a constant & responsive cover image like facebook?

---

P.S: Please note that the user will modify the cover image view point just like what facebook does!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `background-image` instead, so you can set:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

This would stretch the image to fill the entire element without losing ratio.

See the **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w2fLqzc/1/)**

Comment: I have resized the window and the image changed! (see [here](https://ibb.co/iG5F1F)) I don't want this. I want to the image remain the same at different devices, just like fb.